# Primefaces Treetable Text Doesnt fit to Column

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 4.0 and having a treetable component in one of my pages. The width of the first column has some computation problems so when there is indent in the column, the text starts to not fit in the column. When I observe from Chrome Dev Tools, I see that width computation is correct if you dont have the spans for the indentation.

You can see the cases in the images.

Only one row:

[image: Only one row]

Only one row expanded:

[image: Only one row expanded]

Two rows expanded:

[image: Two rows expanded]

Comment: Tried a newer PrimeFaces version? If it works there, check if there is different CSS applied and try to apply that to 4.0. And also check if there is no cusstom css breaking things.

Comment: can u post the xhtml please?

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the CSS code below, the view is fixed but I still think that there is a width computation error when primefaces puts the style class "ui-treetable-indent", it seems width is computed correctly according to the text. If you remove the indentations from column, all the text fits to the column without problem.

```
.ui-treetable thead th:last-child{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding a spacer after the text in the first column.

```
    <p:column>
        <p:outputLabel value="Text to display"/>
        <p:spacer width="30" height="0"/>
    </p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Primefaces 6.1 [04-19-2017] the problem should be solved. Formerly, the problem could indeed only incompletely be solved by p:spacer or CSS.